# Why is extending {0:T} required to enforce the length of a generic array?

Tags: typescript

I saw this [tweet](https://twitter.com/markdalgleish/status/1362702999211008003) that showed a code snippet on how to enforce the length of a generic array in TypeScript. The code snippet is reproduced below:

```
type MyArray<T, Length extends number> = Array<T> & { length: Length }
```

The only problem is, it does not work. As can be seen in this [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCAnRBDEAeAKgGigGQgDsBzYACyggA9giATAZykIFcBbAIwkQD4oBeKElQZMfAGRQA3lAA2RUmQBc+BeSgBfAFBb5wKA2AsAZsZVxhadIcQBLErgDMfQQG0ARAHtCEd7nfAAO6eflABZIgQvgC6QA)

It fails with the following error:

```
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'MyArray<string, 3>'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '{ length: 3; }'.
    Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type '3'.(2322)
```

Later on in the twitter thread, a [solution](https://twitter.com/_luistak/status/1362899328470298626) was proposed actually worked.

This is reproduced below:

```
type MyArray<T extends any, L extends number> = Array<T> & {
    0: T;
    length: L;
}

const foo1: MyArray<number, 5> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

And can be seen in this [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=50&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCAnRBDEAeAKlCAPYEAdgCYDOUKhIANFADI75FlSECuAtgEYSIB8UALxQkqDJgEAyKAG8AsACgoyqAAYAXFEwBuRQEgANkQDmwABaa6uhQF9FigMYB7QqWBQAZk6cBGTXFE0dHZuXloAVgFhAG0fWgAmWgBmWgAWCIBda0UgA)

The question is, what difference does `{0: T}` make? And why is it that extending it makes the code to work?

Comment: I’m not sure, but I wonder if it has to do with the possibility of sparse array?  Adding {0:T} would require that the first index is set.

Answer (score -1):

The type you're using, `string[]`, has to be compatible with both the Array and the { length: Length} types. I believe adding the { 0: T } makes the type compatible with the Array.